# Setting up electron-forge with sveltekit - white screen on package

Tags: javascript, electron, sveltekit, electron-forge

I am in the process of creating an electron-sveltekit starter. I have the development process working as expected but when I go to package the application it only shows a white screen when it is opened. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Here is a link to my repo - https://github.com/N00nDay/sveltekit-electron-starter

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev npm run start:all",
        "start:all": "concurrently -n=svelte,electron -c='#ff3e00',blue \"npm run start:svelte\" \"npm run start:electron\"",
        "start:svelte": "vite dev",
        "start:electron": "electron-forge start",
        "package": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run package:svelte && npm run package:electron",
        "package:svelte": "vite build",
        "package:electron": "electron-forge package",
        "make": "electron-forge make",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "playwright test",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "test:unit": "vitest",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
    },
...
```

**forge.config.cjs**

```
module.exports = {
    packagerConfig: {
        dir: './build'
    },
    rebuildConfig: {},
    makers: [
        {
            name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
            config: {}
        },
        {
            name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
            platforms: ['darwin']
        },
        {
            name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
            config: {}
        },
        {
            name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
            config: {}
        }
    ]
};
```

**svelte.config.cjs**

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            fallback: '/index.html'
        }),
        prerender: {
            entries: []
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

**electron.cjs**

```
const windowStateManager = require('electron-window-state');
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const serve = require('electron-serve');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

try {
    require('electron-reloader')(module);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}

const serveURL = serve({ directory: '.' });
const port = process.env.PORT || 5173;
const dev = !app.isPackaged;
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    let windowState = windowStateManager({
        defaultWidth: 800,
        defaultHeight: 600
    });

    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            spellcheck: false,
            devTools: dev,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.cjs')
        },
        x: windowState.x,
        y: windowState.y,
        width: windowState.width,
        height: windowState.height
    });

    windowState.manage(mainWindow);

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.focus();
    });

    mainWindow.on('close', () => {
        windowState.saveState(mainWindow);
    });

    return mainWindow;
}

function loadVite(port) {
    const appURL = app.isPackaged
        ? url.format({
                pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../build/index.html'),
                protocol: 'file:',
                slashes: true
          })
        : `http://localhost:${port}`;
    mainWindow.loadURL(appURL);

    if (!app.isPackaged) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
}

function createMainWindow() {
    mainWindow = createWindow();
    mainWindow.once('close', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });

    if (dev) loadVite(port);
    else serveURL(mainWindow);
}

app.once('ready', createMainWindow);
app.on('activate', () => {
    if (!mainWindow) {
        createMainWindow();
    }
});
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});

ipcMain.on('to-main', (event, count) => {
    return mainWindow.webContents.send('from-main', `next count is ${count + 1}`);
});
```

**preload.cjs**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
    },
    sendSync: (channel, data) => {
        ipcRenderer.sendSync(channel, data);
    },
    receive: (channel, func) => {
        ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused by a bad path resulting from packaged vs unpackaged paths differing.

**To trace the issue:**

1. Open up the packaged app directory and find your `app.asar`
2. Extract it using `npx @electron/asar extract app.asar appAsar`
3. Ensure your preload script is in the expected directory - it's likely it's in a subdirectory as a result of packaging and that you need to patch the path to adjust for whether the app is packaged or not

For example, in our code we use something like this:

```js
export const preloadPath = path.join(
  __dirname,
  IS_DEV_ENV ? 'dist' : '',
  'preload.build.js'
);
```

**If that still doesn't work** - add `electron-unhandled` to your application by adding these lines to your `main` and `preload` process scripts.

```js
import unhandled from 'electron-unhandled';

unhandled();
```

Be sure to also run `npm install --save electron-unhandled`

This should show you a dialog box with the error that's resulting in a white screen.

If none of that helps, please share your findings from my answer so far and I will examine and update.